# How to convert DateTimeField in django models to specific timezones like GMT?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

Hi is it possible to convert datetime field in django to GMT timezones or what ever timezones we need in the models.py like

```
online_date = models.DateTimeField(timezones=GMT)
```

or should i write in python externally to change the format

Comment: GMT is timezone not format, explain what you exactly need: store value in database as preformated string, update TIMEZONE on already stored values or **display** it in some format/timezone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found it is best to have the server timezone set to UTC and then convert dates based on required timezones (for example, the users preferences), rather than storing different timezoned dates in the database.  This requires no changing of timezones at the layer you are concerned with.